# issues getting output from powershell

Tags: powershell

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'

$ComputerName =Get-ADComputer -Filter {(Name -like "*")} -SearchBase "OU=AsiaPacific,OU=Sales,OU=UserAccounts,DC=FABRIKAM,DC=COM" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

$results = @{}
ForEach ($computer in $ComputerName) {
    $Results += Get-NetAdapter -CimSession $ComputerName | Select-Object PsComputerName, InterfaceAlias, Status, MacAddress
}

$results | Export-csv -path C\users\bret.hooker\desktop\macaddress.csv -Append
```

Please note the base and filter are just examples and not the actual code due to work place confidentiality. Code currently will pull from AD all computer name, then will run the ForEach command to get the NetAdapter Information. I am unable to get it to output to the CSV file however. Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendations are 1) don't continuously append objects to an array, 2) avoid the `-Append` parameter of `Export-Csv`, and 3) take advantage of the pipeline. Example:

```
$computerNames = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=AsiaPacific,OU=Sales,OU=UserAccounts,DC=FABRIKAM,DC=COM" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
$computerNames | ForEach-Object {
  Get-NetAdapter -CimSession $_ | Select-Object PSComputerName,InterfaceAlias,Status,MACAddress
} | Export-Csv "C\users\bret.hooker\desktop\macaddress.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Depending on the size of the data, `ForEach-Object` is an extreme hindrance in speed.

Comment: Not in this example (the computer names are collected before the pipeline runs). There should be little difference in speed between my example and yours: I prefer to avoid appending arrays and simply output each object as you get to it (taking advantage of the pipeline).

Comment: I didn't append arrays ;) and `ForEach-Object` is slower than a `foreach` loop which is slower than the `foreach()` array method.

Comment: My answer never had array appending in it.

Comment: It's about using the right tools for the job.  In a sample of 10,000 objects (I'd consider a decent pool of machines), over 100 iterations, `%` was *twice* as slow as `foreach()` which was *three times* as slow as a `foreach` loop (this surprised me).

Comment: It depends on what you are doing in the loop. I tested your code and mine for this example and the performance was equivalent.